# PHP Laravel 5 uploading a file with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I am trying to upload a file using Laravel 5 and Guzzle.  I am trying to send as form data, but I keep getting a 400 bad request. I tried to use cURL also and got the same error.

Here is what I am trying to use with Guzzle. The API works when I test it in the Postman app while sending it as form-data.

```php
$image = $request->image->storeAs('images', $request->image->getClientOriginalName());
$path = base_path().'/storage/app/';
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'input_profile_image',
            'contents' => fopen($path.'/'.$image, 'r'),
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'input_email',
            'contents' => $email,
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'input_pass',
            'contents' => $password,
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'api_request',
            'contents' => 'true',
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try $client->request('POST',$url,[your array data])

Comment: Looks like it didn't work. Here is what I have `$path = base_path() .'/storage/app/images';
        $data = array('action'=>'update_profile_image',
            'input_email'=>$email,
            'input_pass'=>$password,
            'api_request'=>'true',
            'input_profile_image'=>$path.'/'.$image);

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
        try {
            return $client->request('POST', $this->getUrl(), [$data]);
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            return $e;
        }`

Comment: is your image already saved is storage directory? if no, then you will have to link the storage and public directory by `php artisan storage:link` and then store and fetch the image path from there. your guzzle code is almost correct.

Comment: I added it, for some reason the requests keeps hanging and timing out (I set the timeout to 5 minutes and no size limit on uploads).